# React Google Chrome Extension - Send URL of Current Page from Backend Script to React Component

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have been tasked with making a Google Chrome extension that provides a chatbot for users to ask questions relevant to a YouTube video (will be using the YouTube API - to get the video transcript, and the ChatGPT API for this).

I already have my react component which implements the messaging UI and functionality:

```
// --> chat.jsx

import { useState } from "react";
import "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-styles/dist/default/styles.min.css";

import {
  MainContainer,
  ChatContainer,
  MessageList,
  Message,
  MessageInput,
  TypingIndicator,
} from "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react";
import styles from "./chat-box.module.css";
import "./Chat.css";

const API_KEY = "myapikey";

const Chat = () => {
  const getStrigifiedVideoTranscript = () => {
    // extract the video ID from the URL (the video ID appears after the last '/' in the URL)
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
  };

  const systemMessage = {
    role: "system",
    // todo: refine
    content:
      "Use the provided transcript of the YouTube video to answer any incoming questions" +
      // append the transcript received from the YT API here
      getStrigifiedVideoTranscript(),
  };

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    {
      message:
        "Hey there! I'm your personal YouTube Assistant! What would you like to ask me about the video you're watching?",
      sentTime: "just now",
      sender: "ChatGPT",
    },
  ]);
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  const handleSend = async (message) => {
    const newMessage = {
      message,
      direction: "outgoing",
      sender: "user",
    };

    const newMessages = [...messages, newMessage];

    setMessages(newMessages);

    setIsTyping(true);
    await processMessageToChatGPT(newMessages);
  };

  async function processMessageToChatGPT(chatMessages) {
    let apiMessages = chatMessages.map((messageObject) => {
      let role = "";
      if (messageObject.sender === "ChatGPT") {
        role = "assistant";
      } else {
        role = "user";
      }
      return { role: role, content: messageObject.message };
    });

    const apiRequestBody = {
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [systemMessage, ...apiMessages],
    };

    await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(apiRequestBody),
    })
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setMessages([
          ...chatMessages,
          {
            message: data.choices[0].message.content,
            sender: "ChatGPT",
          },
        ]);
        setIsTyping(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.chatcontainer}>
      <div style={{ height: "500px", width: "400px", marginTop: "2px" }}>
        <MainContainer style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
          <ChatContainer style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
            <MessageList
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                padding: "0px",
                paddingBottom: "10px",
              }}
              scrollBehavior="smooth"
              typingIndicator={
                isTyping ? (
                  <TypingIndicator content="YouTube Question Bot is typing..." />
                ) : null
              }
            >
              {messages.map((message, i) => {
                console.log(message, i);
                return <Message className="msg" key={i} model={message} />;
              })}
            </MessageList>
            <MessageInput placeholder="Ask a question..." onSend={handleSend} />
          </ChatContainer>
        </MainContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

This is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "YouTube Question Bot",
  "description": "Ask any question related to the video you are watching!",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open YouTube Question Bot"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "scripting", "activeTab", "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

and this is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(()=>{
    console.log("hello from background")
})

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    console.log('-->', url)

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url);
});
```

Essentially, I want to receive the message (video URL) sent from here (in background.js), in the `getStrigifiedVideoTranscript()` function in my React component.

How can I achieve this? I've tried looking at solutions online but couldn't find anything solid for messaging between the backend script and a react component.

Comment: You don't need the background script for this. Use chrome.tabs.query in your app (index.html script). Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.